# How to calculate retention rate in elasticsearch/kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-aggregation

The task is to calculate user retention in elastic search. I have documents which contain user id and inside that an array where each element shows some interaction with the system. Each element in the array has a time field.

Is there a way (a query which I can fit in a vega chart or using timelion in kibana, or may be some other alternative) in which I can calculate total unique visitors for lets say 15 days ago and then see the same set of users for each upcoming day?

So that the data shows I had 300 users who visited 15 days ago, then out of those 300, 150 again visited the next day, 120 again visited the next day, and so on.

```
{
"userid":"asdkas213ksashd",
"interaction":[
 {
  "type":1,
  "timestamp":"the date"
 },
 {
  "type":2,
  "timestamp":"the date"
 }]
}
```

Comment: if you have found he solution to this, I'd appreciate if you share it.

Comment: Have anyone found the solution yet please?